# Configuring openssl in mysql

Tags: mysql, openssl

I am using mysql in ubantu 12. I am following [this tutorial](http://xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html) to configure

I have done all process but after restarting mysql 
and running  `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'have_%ssl';`
it is again showing `have_openssl and have_ssl is showing disable`.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Thanks alot  i will ask there        .